# "toLocaleString" giving different output on different browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, locale, currency

```
var num = 1239128938213092131823;
num.toLocaleString('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3, style: 'currency', currency: 'INR'});
```

on chrome:

[image]

on Firefox:

[image]

The Comma pattern output is different in both browsers. Firefox output is what i want and i need the same output in chrome also. Any fixes for this?

> EDIT:
> Recently i checked this on Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116, now the chrome output is same as Firefox output.

Comment: Please note I've updated my answer: it will give you a mostly correct solution.

Comment: Please see my updated updated answer: the solution is fully correct - Chrome has a built-in limitation against using the Rupee symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updating my answer** - my original statement that this was a bug is incorrect.

**Updating again** - found the reason for Chrome showing `Rs.`

The bug refers to something else since you are indeed passing a locale. Changing the locale to use Hindi as used in India (`hi-IN`), I was able to get the following code to display the correctly formatted number on both browsers:

```
num.toLocaleString('hi-IN', {maximumSignificantDigits: 3, style: 'currency', currency: 'INR'});
```

However, you'll note that Chrome will display `Rs.` instead of the Rupee symbol. [This is an intentional decision by Chrome](https://codereview.chromium.org/856153003):

> Use "Rs." instead of the Indian Rupee sign (U+20A8) for which the font
>   support is not available on all platforms.

To get some consistency, you can pass `currencyDisplay: 'code'` as well, which will replace the Rupee symbol with "INR". This works fine on both Chrome and Firefox.

```
num.toLocaleString('hi-IN', {maximumSignificantDigits: 3, style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', currencyDisplay: 'code'});
```

You'll likely want to check if locale and/or [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) support is even available. That can be done with the [following code from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Checking_for_support_for_locales_and_options_arguments) (though as mentioned above, availability does not guarantee similar implementation):

```
function toLocaleStringSupportsLocales() {
  var number = 0;
  try {
    number.toLocaleString('i');
  } catch (e) {
    return e​.name === 'RangeError';
  }
  return false;
}

function toLocaleStringSupportsOptions() {
  return !!(typeof Intl == 'object' && Intl && typeof Intl.NumberFormat == 'function');
}

if(toLocaleStringSupportsLocales()) {
  if(toLocaleStringSupportsOptions()) {
    console.log(num.toLocaleString('hi-IN', {maximumSignificantDigits: 3, style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', currencyDisplay: 'code'}));
  } else {
   // Browser supports locales but does not support Intl options
   console.log(num.toLocaleString('hi-IN'));
  }
} else {
  // Browser does not support locales
  console.error('Cannot format number - locales not supported');
}
```

You should test that the function performs how you want on all browsers/devices, though it should work fine on all major, updated browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matthew.

Comment: @Matthew Firefox dev here, can you please file a bug or paste some code where currencyDisplay isn't working? (123.4).toLocaleString('hi-IN', {maximumSignificantDigits: 3, style: 'currency', currency: 'INR', currencyDisplay: 'code'}) works for me. Thanks.

Comment: @evilpie good call. I didn't realize I was testing on an older machine running Firefox 37. Updated it to 45 and everything works correctly. Answer updated to reflect that. :)

Comment: Thanks for checking.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst this issue is now resolved in latest chrome.